# How to use google Finance API in .Net web application?

Tags: google-finance-api

Has any one used Google Finance API in .Net 4.0? If not 4.0 any version of .net? Please let me know how to start with and helpful resources, links if any.

I need to show Google Finance Data in my web application.

I am good at Bloomberg Finance data API but new to this.

Please help,

Comment: down-vote and that is after one year????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Jigar Please check http://code.google.com/apis/finance/ for this